# tengo un codigo server.js que se supone me inicializa el localhost con dos tablas de JSON (db.JSON y usuarios.JSON), ejecuto node server.js y nada

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Este es el codigo:

```javascript
//archivo server.js
const express = requiere('express');
const app = express();

//carga la base de datos db.json en un objeto llamado "db"
const db = requiere('./db.JSON');

//carga la base de datos usuarios.JSON en un objeto llamdo "usuarios"
const usuarios = requiere('./usuarios.JSON')

//crea un endpoint que devuelve los datos de la base de datos db.json
app.get('/db', (req, res) => {
        res.send(db);
});

//crea un endpoint que devuelve los datos de la base de datos usuarios.json
app.get('/usuarios', (req, res) => {
        res.send(usuarios);
});

//inicializa el servidor en el puerto 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("servidor iniciado en hattp://localhost:3000");
});
```

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero prueba escribiendo el nombre de los archivos JSON con minúscula `'./db.json'`. No se si es case sensitive, pero quizas pueda ser eso. Por otro lado, te da algún mensaje de error en algún lado?

Comment: Podrías aclarar que significa la expresión "ejecuto node server.js y nada"? que error te muestra?
A simple vista veo algunos errores de sintaxis, pero me gustaría que me aclararas ese punto para poder ayudarte

Comment: mas detalles, que esperas que haga el server que te arroja el codigo

Comment: yo espero que este script me inicialice el localhost con las dos tablas o bases de datos.  Pero no lo logro y me responde este error:   

const express = requiere('express');
                ^
ReferenceError: requiere is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (

Comment: const express = requiere('express');
                ^

ReferenceError: requiere is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jebot\OneDrive\ALURA\AluraSuper\server.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)       
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Comment: En vez de escribir requiere('express') deberia ser require('express'). Y en vez de db.JSON, trata de poner db.json (todo en minúsculas). Lo mismo en usuarios.JSON

Comment: Si, tienes muchos `requiere`, pero es `require`

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, el único error que se encuentra en tu código (suponiendo que tus archivos *.JSON son válidos) es que estás utilizando la palabra ´requiere´ en vez de ´require´.

Corrígelo y funcionará.